# How to implement a prioritised collection

Tags: data-structures, collections

I need to implement a prioritised collection.

Assuming we have the following three values in the collection (and their priorities):

```
thisIsUrgent = Priority.High
thisIsImportant = Priority.Medium
thisIsBoring = Priority.Low
```

I want to use `MoveNext()` to go through the collection to get another value.
Assuming I'm looping ten times, each time printing the value from `MoveNext()`, the desired output is:

> thisIsUrgent
>
> thisIsImportant
>
> thisIsUrgent
>
> thisIsUrgent
>
> thisIsBoring
>
> thisIsImportant
>
> thisIsUrgent
>
> thisIsUrgent
>
> thisIsImportant
>
> thisIsBoring

So basically, I get five high priority values, three normal and one low.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the output. Why is it supposed to come out like that?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I think that it picks randomly, but with a higher probability of picking a higher priority task, in the ratio 5:3:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest approach is to have 3 collections behind one interface. When calling `MoveNext` check the one with highest priority, if there are messges return them until queue gets empty. Then lower and lower. Then you can improve algorithm of picking next queue, for example implement probabilistic one.

In your particular case you should use probabilistic scheduling.

- `Urgent` has `5/10 = 0.5`
- `Medium` has `0.3`
- `Low` has `0.2`

At each turn gerate random number in range `[0; 1]`. if value falls into `[0; 0,5]` then pick from `Urgent` queue, if into `[0,5; 0,8]` then `Medium`, `[0,8; 1]` -> `Low`;

Comment: +1 Good idea - as there are only 3 priorities a priority queue would be overkill.

Comment: I don't see how this would provide the output described by the OP. If you had three collections that represented the different priorities, you shouldn't be moving over to a collection of lower priority until the first collection is exhausted.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath it depends on scheduling algorithm. What you say is Fixed priority scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 collections, one for each priority as Andrey says.

Then, when you want to get the next task, pick a random number between 1 and 9.

Retrieve the next task from the relevant collection as follows:

1 to 5: High priority

6 to 8: Normal priority

9     : Low priority

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can clarify your question a little better; it's not immediately obvious why you need your output to be in that particular order. Is the data in one collection, or are there multiple collections?

But if you're looking for a data structure that implements priorities, I suggest going with the tried-and-true [Priority Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).